# REGEX Replacement Syntax for NOTEPAD++ 6.5

Tags: regex

I need to locate strings like R[A-Z][A-Z][0-9] (this syntax works) and replace the first character with 3 which leaving the remaining characters the same.  What is the "replace" syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use this syntax for search: `R([A-Z][A-Z][0-9])`, and this one for the replace: `replacement\1`.

The `\1` in the replacement expression will be the content matched by the group described by the expression between the parentheses.